# SIGHUP equivalent in powershell

Tags: windows, unix, powershell, signals

I am interested in knowing if we can catch SIGINT, SIGHUP equivalent signals in Powershell and how to do it?

I also could not find if there is anything equivalent in powershell like "stty -echo" in unix environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used terminals much, but after some searching to try to understand the significance of `stty -echo` I think you may be able to get a similar effect by creating a helper to PInvoke [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033(v=VS.85).aspx).

As for SIGINT (if I understand it right), I think there are interruption exceptions in .NET and PowerShell.  But that may only be for threads and pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows *has* functionality equivalent to Unix signals in general.
The API functions [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683155%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SetConsoleControlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are
about as close as you're likely to get, but I don't know if they're exposed in any
way by Powershell. I think you're completely out of luck if you need a Windows equivalent 
to some of the more esoteric Unix signals like SIGHUP.

**Edit**: I see from one of the answers to your previous question that Powershell
does have a `trap` command -- but it seems to handle .Net exceptions, which
I wouldn't consider equivalent to Unix signals.

About an equivalent for `stty -echo` -- sorry, no idea.

Comment: anything about "stty -echo"?
Thanks for your reply.